# How to convert WEI to ETH with ethers.js

Tags: ether

How do you convert WEI to ETH? How do you convert WEI to ETH? How do you convert WEI to ETH?

Had to repost because it wouldn't let me post once.

Answer (score 35):

Take a look a `formatEther` in the ethers.js [documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v4/api-utils.html#ether-strings-and-wei)

```
const weiValue = 100000;
const ethValue = ethers.utils.formatEther(weiValue);
```

You can also format an arbitrary amount of Wei into any other denomination using `formatUnits`.

```
const gweiValue = ethers.utils.formatUnits(weiValue, "gwei");
```

Answer (score 2):

To let it work fine with (e) format use that:

```
const balanceInWei = (+(await ethers.provider.getBalance(
  address
))).toLocaleString("fullwide", { useGrouping: false });

const balanceInEth= ethers.utils.formatEther(balanceInWei);
```